# Android: Viewpager with listview is not scrolling on certain phones?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, focus, android-viewpager

I have an activity which manages a viewpager of 5 fragments each with their own listview or gridview.  The implementation works perfectly on my Galaxy S4 but gets very wonky on my old Droid Bionic.  On the Bionic the viewpager can swipe right and left between fragments correctly but when I scroll vertically (up and down) the listviews will not scroll and seems like the fragments "behind" the current fragment are intercepting the focus. (Just a note..I am not doing anything like intercepting touch events anywhere).  I can manage to scroll vertically if I start my touch on certain items in the listviews like buttons/text which leads me to believe it could be something to do with focus.

I just dont understand why it would work on my S4 but not the Droid Bionic. Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: What do you mean "fragments behind the current fragment" ?

Comment: Sorry I should probably clarify.  So the viewpager allows the user to swipe between fragments. It seems as though the fragment to the right of the fragment currently in focus is getting the touch inputs instead (the viewpager by default has an off screen page limit of 2). But I've only seen this on the Droid Bionic, I havent tested it yet on other phones.

Comment: I see. The thing is, my ViewPager displays 2 fragments at the same time, side-by-side (in landscape view, the screen is split down the middle). Only one of these views can have the focus at a time, however, regardless of which has it, I can freely scroll lists in either one. I'll keep your issue in mind, and hopefully find something soon. Could be a bug with that phone. I've seen views not behave correctly across platforms. I'd try testing it on some other devices before concluding anything though.

Comment: Yeah thats what I plan on doing.  Its working perfectly on my S4 so im not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Have you ever used setCurrentItem ? It's a pragmatic way to scroll/set the current fragment in a ViewPager.  Just as a test, I would call this , ideally in an event override when the ViewPager switches pages (if one exists, like onPageChanged or something). Its got a bool flag that determines if the page will scroll-animate when switching to, or just pop in.

Comment: I am currently using it.  The user has the option of swiping between pages or clicking the action bar menu item which opens a sliding drawer and from there they can select a page.  That is where I use setCurrentItem to go to that page in the viewpager and it looks like it scroll animates (very fast) currently.

Comment: Ok, and do you have this list-scrolling issue in both cases (when the user swipe-selects and/or click-selects to the current page)?

Comment: The issue occurs the moment I load up the app on the bionic. I havent tested the slide and select yet..at work now so I cant test that till later.  I am going to try explicitly setting an OnScrollListener to the listviews but have them do nothing...maybe thats it?

Comment: I can not only scroll either the left or right page, but both at the same time as well (with two fingers), fyi.

Comment: Im really hoping it is just some bug with the bionic.